# Qt 5.5 missing MYSQL driver

Tags: mysql, qt, qt-creator

Today I started working with Qt 5.5 and my first project is to get GPS related data form a MYSQL database and send to another server. The problem is that I have a linking problem with the `libqmysql.so` driver file. I looked after how to solve the problem and I did the following steps so far:

- I copied all the files (`libqmysql.so` and other drivers) into `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers` and `/home/magyarg/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc/plugins/sqldrivers`
- I ran `ldd libqmysql.so` to check what dependencies are needed; I got the following result:

[image]
According this result, I installed `libssl` and `libmysqlclient18`.

### The problem:

After these steps Qt Creator still throws me the the error:

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
> QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7

### The environment:

- Ubuntu Linux 15.04(x86)
- Qt5.5

### The corresponding code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtSql>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("ugyfelhivo");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("pass");
    bool ok = db.open();
    if (ok == true) {
        QLabel label;
        label.setText("Macska");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to re-compile driver (qmqsql) by yourself

Comment: Just look close! The plugin wants libmysqlclient16, but you installed libmysqlclient18! Either compile the plugin yourself or get the v16 from somwhere

Comment: Please don't link images of text - copy+paste the error message into your question (that way, it gets indexed better for searching).

Comment: What OS?  You shouldn't have to manually copy files around; simply installing `libqt5sql5-mysql` should put things in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Often this solution works to get the QMYSQL loaded:

```
cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -s libmysqlclient_r.so.18 libmysqlclient_r.so.16
```